# .NET Core 1.0.0-preview3-004056 MacOSX El Capitan - System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't resolve host name

Tags: .net, curl, httpclient

i'm running a HttpClient "Post" to an Oauth2 service to retreive a token.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

//HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = tokenRequestBaseUri;

List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
nameValueCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));

System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueCollection);

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URIHelper.GetUAATokenRequestRelativeUri());

request.Content = formContent;

string clientId_clientSecret = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tenantInformation.ClientId_svcops + ":" + tenantInformation.ClientSecret_svcops));
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", clientId_clientSecret);

logger.Debug("Sending Http Request");

var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Code is running properly on Windows 7 but the same code on MacOSX El Capitan throw an exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't resolve host name
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAgent.FinishRequest(StrongToWeakReference`1 easyWrapper, CURLcode messageResult)
```

> Couldn't resolve host name

But if i open the browser i can browse that Url!

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: probably an issue in the coreClr you should post an issue on github instead of posting it here. (Especcially when using preview build versions)

Comment: Has this been posted on Github? I'm getting a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2017 RC and the Preview 3 of .NET Core SDK solved the issue.

It align the framework version on both Windows and MAC OS.